# Change timezone in "timestamp" when inserting data into a database using SQL

Tags: mysql, server, backend

I'm creating a stock exchange website where users can buy and sell stocks whenever they want using a couple of forms in html. Every time the users do these I run a SQL query to insert data into the database about which stock was bought, number of stocks and the day,year and time they did that operation.

The complete data base structure in SQL is the following:

```
CREATE TABLE 'users_cash_track' ( id INT, symbol TEXT NOT NULL, name TEXT NOT NULL, shares INT , price INT, total INT NOT NULL, total_stock_boug INT, total_after_purchase INT, 'transac_d' timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP )
```

The query I run to insert data into the Table :

```
db.execute("INSERT INTO users_cash_track (id,symbol,name,shares,price,total, total_stock_boug,total_after_purchase) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",id,symbol,name_stock,num_shares,price_stock,stock_bought,total_stock_boug,total_after_purchase
```

As you can see I'm using "timestamp" with "current_timestamp" as default to know for example when the user bought a TSLA stock on the 2021-02-08-15:34.

The only the problem that I have is that the server of the database is located in a different time zone(no idea which UTC is jaja) than the one I am living (GMT-5) I want the 'transac_d' value to be posted in the database with my UTC(GMT-5) and not the one of the server host!!

I google a lot and looked at previous post here but they dont answer properly the problem.Really appreciate the help thanks a lot guys!! :)

Comment: TIMESTAMP always stores the value in UTC. The value is adjusted during both save and retrieve to the server timezone. *I want the 'transac_d' value to be posted in the database with my UTC(GMT-5) and not the one of the server host* Use DATETIME, not TIMESTAMP - its value is stored/retrieved as provided, without timezone adjustment.

Comment: Don't confuse data storage with data display.

Comment: BTW - There is no such thing as "my UTC", UTC is the same for everyone everywhere hence why it is call UNIVERSAL

Comment: When I use DATETIME in the data type with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP the same happens and the info is provided with the server time and not my GTM-5 zone :( thanks for trying to help any other ideas?